# shell script to update a set of txt files

Tags: shell

I would like using shell or any script to modify all txt files available in myfolder as follow

```
 test = data(x, y);
```

with

```
test = data(z,x,y);  // by adding z
```

and :

```
 test.value(f1, "directory_1/directory_2/directory_3/file");
```

with

```
test.value(f1, "/directory_3/file"); // by removing directory_1/directory_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed with bash:

```
for i in *.txt; do
  if [ -f $i ]; then
    sed -i 's!test = data(\s*x,\s*y)!test = data(z,x,y)!' "$i"
    sed -i 's!test.value(f1, "[^/]*/[^/]*\(/[^"]*\)");!test.value(f1, "\1");!' "$i"
  fi  
done
```

Comment: There is no need to run `sed` twice. You can combine two commands into one with `-e` option or even just delimit them with `;`.

Comment: And no need for the `for` loop, `sed ... *.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd myfolder
for FILE in *txt ; do
    sed -i 's/test = data(x,\s*y);/test = data(z,x,y);/;/test.value(f1, "/s="[^/]*/[^/]*\(/[^/]*/[^/]*");\)$=\1=;' "$FILE"
done
```

if your sed isn't GNU, then use

```
cd myfolder
for FILE in *txt ; do
    sed 's/test = data(x, y);/test = data(z,x,y);/test.value(f1, "/s="[^/]*/[^/]*\(/[^/]*/[^/]*");\)$=\1=;' "$FILE" > "$FILE.tmp"
    mv "${FILE}.tmp" "$FILE"
done
```